# Relationships and forms in Libreoffice Base

Tags: database, libreoffice, libreoffice-base

I'm auditing some servers and I have a table called "Servers" with a few fields.

One of these is a field called "users"

I have another table called "users" which holds information on each user. Of course, there are many "root" users (one for each server) so I don't know if a single table for users is appropriate for this.

Information on users include things like their SSH key, username, home directory etc. What's the best way of designing a database, and a form to enter this information easily?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a single table for all users is appropriate

Forget about the `users` field in your `servers` table, this isn't how relationships work in relational databases.

Your `users` table should have a field (perhaps called `server_id`) which has a foreign key relationship with "server"'s primary key.

Once you have your 2 tables set up you can use the form wizard to create a form for `servers` which has a `subform` for `users` and `libreoffice` will do most of the work for you in laying it out, just select all fields for the `subform` apart from `server_id` (the `subform` will manage that for you)

You may also want to consider splitting ssh keys into a separate table and further nested `sub-form`, as users can have more than one.

---

Bear in mind that this solution is not fully normalized, any time a user has an account on more than one server there is potential for duplication. However designing a fully normalized database for your audit seems like it will be overkill and will make working with `libreoffice` base much harder.